# What song has the lyrics "I used to think my mother was the Shabbos Queen"

Tags: song-poetry

What song has these lyrics? I don't remember them so clearly.

It goes something like:

> I used to think my mother was the Shabbos Queen,
>
> She stands so regally in royal grace,
>
> I know my mother doesn’t ask for diamonds...

This is a song by Yocheved Sorscher

Comment: Welcome to mi yodea! As you may have noticed this site is a bit different than other sites. Please consider taking the site tour https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour you have a perfectly good question but this just may be the wrong forum for it. For guidance on what’s considered on topic here have a look at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Googling the first line you quote tells me the song is "Shabbos Queen" (via [1](http://jewishsonglyrics.blogspot.com/2007/09/shabbos-queen.html), [2](http://www.jyrics.com/lyrics/shabbos-queen/)).

Comment: How is this considered on topic?

Comment: @Mordechai, the _Shabas_ queen is a concept of Judaism.

Comment: @msh This seems to be “Judaism as applies to non-Jewish concepts,” not inherently a Jewish question, which is why I voted to close; seems the community agrees with that reading.

Comment: @DonielF, it's a question about the title of a text about Judaism. It's like if someone asked "I've heard Maimonides's law book called by different names.... What's its actual title?". Would that be off-topic?